# How to load partitioned parquet dataset with no partition names (in directory names)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of files in parquet format

```
-- s3:\\my-bucket\files\14\09\12\file.pq
-- s3:\\my-bucket\files\14\09\11\file.pq
# 14 = day, 09 = month, 11 = hour.
```

if I pass the absolute path to my spark context it can read the file without any issue

```
spark.read.parquet('s3:\\my-bucket\files\14\09\12\file.pq')
```

if I pass in

```
spark.read.parquet('s3:\\my-bucket\files\14')
```

then I will get the following error:

```
AnalysisException: 'Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;'
```

This is, I believe due to the fact the partitions are unnamed, I have no control over the source so I can't change it unfortunately.

my hacky work around is to list all the files and then take the unique set of lowest level paths and pass that into spark .

Is there a better work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easier way is putting `*` to list all directories within path:

```py
df = spark.read.parquet('s3://my-bucket/files/*/*/*/')
```

If you want retrieve `day`, `month` and `hour`, [follow my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65386616/predicate-pushdown-on-non-partitioned-parquet-data/65394192#65394192)

Comment: hmm, this leads to another error - saying that no such file can be found for a given parquet file, although when I inspect it via the cli `aws s3 ls file_path` it's there. Not sure if its related to my error above

Comment: Your parquet file extension is `.pq`, but it should be `.parquet`. Try changing the path to `s3://my-bucket/files/*/*/*/*.pq`

Comment: ah the error was due to glue bookmarks, it struggles when trying to read in a large amount of files.. no idea what causes it but seems like others have had the same issue. Thanks for your help!